# how to detect when animation is completed

Tags: apache-flex, animation

i have a mx:AdvancedDataGrid control with animation on resize. And i need to resize another contol A accordingly with mx:AdvancedDataGrid size. But resizing of contol A is too slow.

Threrefore, the addition of resize handler is bad solution. I want to get the time when the animation is completely stopped either the new size of mx:AdvancedDataGrid control. Please advise me a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an eventListener to the `effectEnd` event of the Resize effect:

```
<mx:Resize effectEnd='myEventHandler()' id="resizeEffect" />
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid resize="{resizeEffect}" />
```